# Best way to store / retrieve this data in IOS ( a single word and a path to a file )

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know there are probably many ways to do this.

I am wondering what direction I should look into for this. I need speed and ease of use. I'm going to guess go with an associative array. But interested in what the seasoned ios developers have to say on it.

basically it will be about 50-200 items. No more than that. Each item containing a single word and a path to a file. ( note that details of the file will be processed / incorporated into the app at runtime ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is a string. The path is a string. The pairing between word and path is a dictionary. NSDictionary can write itself to and read itself from a file. Done. You won't even need to "process" anything: the file will simply spring to life as an NSDictionary, ready for use.

Comment: Easy to work with NSDictionary in an Array like fashion?

Comment: Save an array of dictionaries. Each entry in the array will contain both a word string and a path string.

Comment: @FannyDarmer Why is an array needed? A dictionary consists of many key-value pairs. Here, each word is a key, with the corresponding path as the corresponding value. NSDictionary is Objective-C's "associative array" that you were talking about.

Comment: I need some semblance of order. What if I used these with the key being its incremental number value and its value being a comma separated list of Word and FileName?

Comment: What if you used @DuncanC's suggestion of an NSArray of NSDictionaries? That, too, can save itself to a file and restore itself from a file.

Comment: Yes. I think this is a good suggestion. Thanks everyone who helped out on this.

Comment: What do you guys think about creating an array of objects here instead?

Comment: Perfectly reasonable, but you'll have to archive and unarchive the objects. The advantage of the array of dictionaries of strings is that the array saves and restores itself. See the discussion of this topic in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_saving_and_reading_files

Answer (score 1):

200 NSStrings - don't bother with anything more than just writeToFile: and initWithContentsOfFile: methods to read /write your NSDictionary. All other solution like CoreData sounds too heavy for your needs.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfile.plist"]; 

//write to file
[yourdictionary writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];

//load from file
NSMutableDictionary *loadedDictonary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

Comment: I need some semblance of order. What if I used these with the key being its incremental number value and its value being a comma separated list of Word and FileName?

Answer (score 1):

It just depends on how your data maters to your app:
If it is just data supporting your app, you can easily make them and store them into the preference of your app:

`NSDictionary * allUrls = @{ @"aString":@"a/path/to/a/file", @"string2" : @"url2" ...}`

`NSUserDefaults * preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

`[preferences setObject:allUrls forKey:@"ALL URLS"];`

Then to retrieve it from anywhere in your app :

`NSUserDefaults * preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

`NSDictionary * allUrls = [preferences objectForKey:@"ALL URLS"];`

Comment: the downside of this is if the user deletes the app he will lose the NSUserDefaults